# I need to group a view by first initial (A,B,C) but both A and a are considered separate groups

Tags: 7, views

How can I get views to group upper and lowercase together?

I have the title field added twice in the view and the second instance under REWRITE RESULTS I have "Trim this field to a maximum length" of 1.  My view is grouped by this second field (so the first letter of the title.)

I have tried glossary mode with a contextual filter and that also didn't yield results.

Do I have to convert the field with strtoupper in a view template to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, a workaround is with twig. Choose the option to *Override the output of this field with custom text* and then use twig to capitalize.

```
{{ my_field|upper }}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is drupal 7.  I don't want to rewrite the field with php due to security reasons and adding a span to create upper case doesn't seem to work.